# Multithreaded Regex?

Tags: regular-expressions, parallel-computing

I once had an idea for a multithreaded regex engine.

The first method that occured to me (there may be other ways to do it that I haven't thought of) was to split up the string being matched against into chunks and it would introduce parallelism by having the coroutines which are processing the string hand off to the next coroutine where it left off, informing it of its progress (e.g. whether it is in middle of a possible match). This paradigm would also solve some issues with out of memory exceptions with long strings, because some memory could be cleared once it ran out, and start as if from the beginning from where it was when the memory exception occurred, carrying over a minimal amount of information. This may not work for some regexes, but shouldn't there at least be a subset of regexes that can be parallelized?

Does this make sense?

Is there a reason that parallel regexing isn't possible, and therefore this whole thought process is futile?

Comment: Seems possible, but maybe not when there aren't suitable chunks. e.g. match the string (20000000 "a"s then a "b") against the regex (10000000 "a"s then a "b")